# Querying using `database/sql` is significantly slower than querying the database directly

Tags: postgresql, go, psql

I'm running the same query against a local postgresql instance using a golang application, and using `psql`. The timings differ greatly and I'm wondering why. Using explain/analyze the query took 1ms, using `database/sql` in golang, it took 24ms. I've added my code snippets below. I realize that explain/analyze may not be equivalent to querying the database directly, and there may be some network latency involved as well, however the discrepancy is still significant. Why is there such a discrepancy?

edit: I've tried the above with a sample size of 10+ queries, and the discrepancy still holds true.

```
postgres=# \timing
Timing is on.
postgres=# select 1;
 ?column?
----------
        1
(1 row)

Time: 2.456 ms
postgres=# explain analyze select 1;
                                     QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.017 ms
 Execution Time: 0.012 ms
(3 rows)

Time: 3.748 ms
```

```
package main

    import (
        "database/sql"
        "fmt"
        _ "github.com/lib/pq"
        "time"
    )

    func main() {
        // setup database connection
        db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host='localhost' port=5432 user='postgres' password='' dbname='postgres' sslmode=disable")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        // query database
        firstQueryStart := time.Now()
        _, err = db.Query("select 1;")
        firstQueryEnd := time.Now()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("first query took %s", firstQueryEnd.Sub(firstQueryStart).String()))

        //run the same query a second time and measure the timing
        secondQueryStart := time.Now()
        _, err = db.Query("select 1;")
        secondQueryEnd := time.Now()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("second query took %s", secondQueryEnd.Sub(secondQueryStart).String()))
    }
```

```
first query took 13.981435ms
second query took 13.343845ms
```

Comment: Do it a second time and measure how fast the second one is. You might be astonished.

Comment: @Volker Hi! I extended my script to attempt the query a 2nd time (in order to use the same connection), and the timing didn't change.
```
1st query Took 27.962703ms to write to database
2nd query Took 22.314491ms to write to database
```

Comment: Interesting. `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` does execute the insert with actual side effects. Are you certain your `psql` is not having an open transaction.

I would try executing another statement first on Go side, if not just `SELECT 1;` to ensure that it is not some lazy initialization that is causing this, and then timing only after that.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, I updated my example go code. There was a slight difference using select to initialize the connection, however the performance is no where close to using psql. I think this is the same as running the query twice, as the first attempt should have initialized the connection. I've tried with a larger sample size as well, and the writes take 20ms+

Comment: *"I'm running the same query"* is not true, on psql you're using a plain query, on the go side you rely on prepared statements. That of course does not mean that a prepared statement should be so much slower than an equivalent plain query, just that the two are not the same thing and are executed differently regardless of what client you're using. If you want to *actually* execute the same query on both clients, don't use parameter placeholders in the go version, instead use the same exact `select` statement as in `psql`.

Comment: Hi @mkopriva, I don't see where a `database/sql` is preparing a statement before execution. In the script above, I'm calling `Query`, and I don't see the library using a prepare statement under the covers.
@AnttiHaapala the suggestion to use `SELECT 1;` is really useful. I was able to duplicate the issue using `SELECT 1`. I'll update my question/code to reflect it

Comment: `github.com/lib/pq` is pure go whereas psql uses `libpq`. There seems to be a libpq based driver at [github-gopgsqldriver](https://github.com/jbarham/pgsql.go/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: @AnuragM If you didn't see it, that just means you've been looking under the wrong covers.

Comment: Next test, use prepared statements in PSQL: `PREPARE select1 AS SELECT 1; EXECUTE select1;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note #1**: [`sql.DB`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB) does not represent *a* connection, instead it represents a *pool* of connections.

**Note #2**: [`sql.Open`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open) initializes the pool but it *does not* have to actually open a connection, it's allowed to only validate the dsn input and then the opening of the connections will be handled lazily by the pool.

The reason your **1st** `db.Query` is slow is because you're starting off with a fresh connection pool, one that has 0 idle (but open) connections, and therefore the **1st** `db.Query` will need to first establish a new connection to the server and only after that will it be able to execute the sql statement.

The reason your **2nd** `db.Query` is also slow is because the connection created by the **1st** `db.Query` has not been released back to the pool, and therefore your **2nd** `db.Query` will also need to first establish a new connection to the server before it can execute the sql statement.

---

To release a connection back to the pool you need to first retain the primary return value of `db.Query` and then invoke the [`Close`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Close) method on it.

To start off with a pool that has at least one available connection, call [`Ping`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Ping) right after initializing the pool.

---

Example:

```golang
func main() {
    // setup database connection
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres:///?sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        // query database
        firstQueryStart := time.Now()
        rows, err := db.Query("select 1;")
        firstQueryEnd := time.Now()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        // put the connection back to the pool so
        // that it can be reused by next iteration
        rows.Close()

        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("query #%d took %s", i, firstQueryEnd.Sub(firstQueryStart).String()))
    }
}
```

Times on my machine (without `db.Ping` only #0 is slow)

```
query #0 took 6.312676ms
query #1 took 102.88µs
query #2 took 66.702µs
query #3 took 64.694µs
query #4 took 208.016µs
```

Times on my machine (with `db.Ping` #0 is a lot faster than without)

```
query #0 took 284.846µs
query #1 took 78.349µs
query #2 took 76.518µs
query #3 took 81.733µs
query #4 took 103.862µs
```

---

#### A note on prepared statements:

If you're executing a simple query with no arguments e.g. `db.Query("select 1 where true")` then you really are executing just a simple query.

If, however, you're executing a query with arguments e.g. `db.Query("select 1 where $1", true)` then, in actuality, you are creating and executing a prepared statement.

See [4.2. Value Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html), it says:

> A value expression is one of the following: ...
>
> - A positional parameter reference, **in the body of a function definition or prepared statement**
>   ...

Also [Positional Parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html#SQL-EXPRESSIONS-PARAMETERS-POSITIONAL) says:

> A positional parameter reference is used to indicate a value that is
> supplied externally to an SQL statement. **Parameters are used in SQL
> function definitions and in prepared queries**. Some client libraries
> also support specifying data values separately from the SQL command
> string, in which case parameters are used to refer to the out-of-line
> data values.

How the postgres' message-flow protocol specifies [`simple queries`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-flow.html#id-1.10.5.7.4) and [`extended queries`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-flow.html#PROTOCOL-FLOW-EXT-QUERY)

> The extended query protocol breaks down the above-described simple
> query protocol into multiple steps. The results of preparatory steps
> can be re-used multiple times for improved efficiency. Furthermore,
> **additional features are available, such as the possibility of
> supplying data values as separate parameters instead of having to
> insert them directly into a query string.**

And finally, under the covers of the [`lib/pq`](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/083382b7e6fc78cc91eb57afab268fe2f1b6ed6d/conn.go#L834-L855) driver:

```golang
    ...

    // Check to see if we can use the "simpleQuery" interface, which is
    // *much* faster than going through prepare/exec
    if len(args) == 0 {
        return cn.simpleQuery(query)
    }

    if cn.binaryParameters {
        cn.sendBinaryModeQuery(query, args)

        cn.readParseResponse()
        cn.readBindResponse()
        rows := &rows{cn: cn}
        rows.rowsHeader = cn.readPortalDescribeResponse()
        cn.postExecuteWorkaround()
        return rows, nil
    }
    st := cn.prepareTo(query, "")
    st.exec(args)
    return &rows{
        cn:         cn,
        rowsHeader: st.rowsHeader,
    }, nil

    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Not releasing the connection back to the pool was the issue.