# Gorm with postgres taking too long on first sql

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm using Gorm with postgres driver. I'm testing some queries and realize the first query will always be very slow (100ms +). I've tested the same benchmark in MySQL, and that not occurs.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

var config = gorm.Config{
    PrepareStmt:            true,
    SkipDefaultTransaction: true,
}

func main() {
    dsn := "postgresql://postgres:senha123@localhost:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable"

    start := time.Now()
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &config)
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }

    fmt.Printf("==> Open connection: %s\n", time.Since(start))
    executeBenchmark(db)
}

func executeBenchmark(db *gorm.DB) {
    user := &User{
        Name:     "Inserted",
        Email:    "m@m.com",
        Password: "asdf",
    }

    // Test Create performance
    start := time.Now()
    db.Create(&user)
    fmt.Printf("==> Create user: %s\n", time.Since(start))

    // Test Select by email performance
    start = time.Now()
    db.Where(&User{Email: user.Email}).First(&user)
    fmt.Printf("==> Select by EMAIL user: %s\n", time.Since(start))

    // Test Update performance
    start = time.Now()
    db.Model(&user).Where(&User{ID: user.ID}).Update("name", "updated")
    fmt.Printf("==> Update user: %s\n", time.Since(start))

    // Test delete performance
    start = time.Now()
    db.Unscoped().Delete(&User{}, user.ID)
    fmt.Printf("==> Delete User user: %s\n", time.Since(start))
}
```

Postgres result:

```
==> Open connection: 3.1902ms
==> Create user: 122.5041ms
==> Select by EMAIL user: 2.3431ms
==> Update user: 2.7019ms
==> Delete User user: 1.1994ms
```

If I execute the `Select by EMAIL user` first, it will be the slow query instead...

Running the same benchmark with MySQL:

```
==> Open connection: 6.2952ms
==> Create user: 8.98ms
==> Select by EMAIL user: 1.3064ms
==> Update user: 3.6067ms
==> Delete User user: 3.0996ms
```

Go: 1.20 
gorm: 1.25.0 
driver postgres: 1.5.0 
driver MySQL: 1.5.0

I want to understand why the first query always takes 100ms+ and how I can improve it. Please, help =)

Comment: I don't use gorm so I don't know for sure but, the reason is probably the same as the one causing similar behaviour in the stdlib's `database/sql`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64786316/965900

Comment: @mkopriva The idea is interesting, but I don't know how I can do that with Gorm. Reading the docs, it seems I dont have much control with the DB instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know why this is happening, but I ran this benchmark inside a docker container using the same db network and I got better results:

```
==> Open connection: 336.317µs
==> Create user: 7.741506ms
==> Select by EMAIL user: 999.892µs
==> Update user: 1.034811ms
==> Delete User user: 912.888µs
```

The first SQL is still the worst, but I think it is fine. I'll assume that the problem was something in my localhost with docker...